# Object is too big when load from database symfony

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.4

I need load and object from the database and need to store it in session .

The problem is that the loaded object is too big that when i print it my browse crushes .

How can i load just the pure object from the database ?

And here is the code :

```
if ($session->get('record')->getId()) {
    $record = $this->container->get('myweb.record_repository')->findOneById($session->get('record')->getId());
    $session->set('record', $record);
    print_r($session->get('record'));
    die;
}
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear enough. How do you dump your data? In Twig or in Controller? Add some code... We need to see how you do things to understand your problem. I dump a lot of data myself when I dev, and it never happened. Second, why are you trying to store a whole object into session? If, like I've read in the comments on Alex Pab answer, your object is related to other, it's better to get a fresh copy each time.

Comment: @Preciel i dump the data in the controller ,
I need to get the object from database (object related to many others) and store it in the session , client needs that ...

Answer (score 0):

Try to hydrate as array... in symfony there is the option to Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY and then normalize it to an object

Comment: How can i cast the returned object from the query to the original object form ?

Comment: What Alex Prab suggested is to work with an array, rather than with your object...
Do you need your whole object ? or just some properties ?
What do you want to achieve ? To store in session may be not the proper solution for your need...

Comment: My object is already related to other objects example :
$record->getPersonnalDetails()->getName(); 
I need to get the whole object ...

Comment: What DBMS do you use? I use doctrine in my symfony project and after receiving the object as array, i write my own normalizer where i build my object with the data i receive...
you also don't have to work with the whole object, so you can only use the data you need from your object!

Comment: Again, what do you want to achieve exactly ? 1st time that I see that someone wants to store in session a huge amount of data...

Comment: Yess i use doctrine too , but my problem is that i have too many other objects related to this object named record , but when i used Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY i got only the fields in the record table , 
im having this because i used cascade persist (from the object record you can go to others that have the record_id )

Comment: Normally if you dump what you receive as array, all data should be included.. then you call a the normalizer with the method normalize, where you normalize every object data in the array... but as @DhiaEddineAyadi said, what data do you need? if you don't need the object work with the data from the array... if the array doesn't include the data you need, you are missing something in the query...

Comment: This should have been a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're not dumping your code correctly.

With Symfony, there is the `dump()` function.

You can either use it in controller, or in twig.

In controller:

```
//Check if parameter exists first, else you might trigger an error
if($session->has('record') && $session->get('record')->getId() !== null) {
    $record = $this->container->get('myweb.record_repository')->findOneById($session->get('record')->getId());
    $session->set('record', $record);
    dump($session->get('record'));
    exit();
}
```

In Twig (you can pass a variable name)

```
{{ dump() }}
```

Then again, like I said in comment, it's most likely pointless to store your object in session.
Doctrine will query for the object most of the time.

Lets say you do this:

```
$relatedEntity->getRecord();
```

Doctrine won't look into the session for the object, it will query database.